Continue to a line while debugging in VS Code
Is there a way to bring debugger to specific line while debugging in VS Code without multiple f10 or placing breakpoints all over code. eg. Visual Studio has below way to continue the debugger to specific line. 
Couldn't found any way to do so. Please let me know if there is any way to do so.

The best way could be: place cursor on line where to stop, followed by hitting F9 F5 F9.
